# Complex Types of Nullable Values

Tags: c#, entity-framework

For a complex type in entity framework with only nullable properties, why is that for something like the following requires the complex type be instantiated:

```
[ComplexType]
public class Address {
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
}

public class Customer {
    [Key]
    public int CustomerId {get;set;}
    public Address Address {get;set;}
}
```

More specifically, if you don't declare and address type, you get a "Null value for non-nullable member. Member: 'Address'." As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856202/required-properties-on-optional-entity-framework-complex-types).

As long as all the properties in the complex type are nullable, why is it that entity framework requires an instance of Address? Since Address1 is nullable, why can it not just assume that and create the table (and column Address_Address1) and null value in the row as if I had created an instance of Address with a null Address1?

Or is there an attribute/fluent setting I can apply to achieve that?

Comment: May be you are not allocated memory for address using null operator.

Comment: This is a really bad feature of EF. Using reflection on an Address object, EF can easily work out what columns to create on table creation. It doesn't need to have an instance of Address from the entity to work that out. And on entity creation/updating, if the ComplexType property was null, what's so hard about setting those columns in the database to null? This should be an easy feature addition to the next version of EF IMO.

Answer (score 8):

look at this question [Entity Framework 5 DbUpdateException: Null value for non-nullable member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279042/entity-framework-5-dbupdate-error).

you need to instantiate the complex type even if all the properties are null.

Comment: In my case I didn't have instantiated the complex type (the instance has no null property by the way) and I'm getting this exception

Answer (score 8):

Even if the properties are nullable, the class containing them isn't. You can have `Address.Address1` as `null`, but `Address` itself has to be instantiated.

Comment: Of course the class Address is nullable as it is not a value type, but the problem lies with EF itself and its handling of "complex types".

Comment: It's not limited to EF complex types; if `Address` is null you're not going to be able to access `Address.Address1` without a null reference exception. Although I admit this answer was badly phrased; I wrote it in a hurry. I'll fix it at some point.

Comment: Of course but if Address was not a complex type here (e.g. a navigation property) then null would be totally acceptable. So the "Null value for non-nullable member" error is really linked to the fact that "Address" was declared as a complex type for EF.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, I think we've been talking at cross purposes here; you're totally right.