# Allow class properties to be null in WebAPI 2 post methods

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2

I am using two POCO classes:

```
public class GearModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public Int16 LocationNumber { get; set; }
    public string HooksPerRod { get; set; }
    public string TerminalWeightBait { get; set; }
    public string TerminalWeight { get; set; }
    public FlyModel Shrimps { get; set; }
    public FlyModel Worms { get; set; }
    public FlyModel Cocahoes { get; set; }
    public FlyModel Scampi { get; set; }
}

public class FlyModel
{
    public double? Number { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to posts to my API Controller (defined below), it Complains `Null value for non-nullable member. Member: 'Worms'.`, when using this cURL command to post to it (I know none of the cURL parameters are the issue, if I include all the `FlyModel` properties it works).

Not Working

---

`curl -X POST -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-ascii "{Assn:102,LocationNumber:1,HooksPerRod:3,TerminalWeightBait:'None',TerminalWeight:'18oz',Shrimps:{Number:0.0,Color:'Pink'}}" <Url Here>`

Working

---

`curl -X POST -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-ascii "{Assn:102,LocationNumber:1,HooksPerRod:3,TerminalWeightBait:'None',TerminalWeight:'18oz',Shrimps:{Number:0.0,Color:'Pink'},Worms:{},Cocahoes:{},Scampi:{}}" <Url Here>`

So my question is, how do I allow the FlyModel properties (Shrimps, Worms, etc) to be completely left out of the JSON like in the not working cURL command?

GearController

---

```
public class GearController : ApiController
{
    // POST: api/Gear
    [ResponseType(typeof(GearModel))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostGearModel(GearModel gearModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Gear.Add(gearModel);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = gearModel.Assn }, gearModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a bit odd, I do this all the time in WebAPI and cannot remember having to configure anything as that was the default behaviour.  I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the error after `db.SaveChangesAsync();`which is by `Entity Framework`, `Web Api` does not change anything here. The error happens because `EF` does not allow complex types nullability, that means **you need to instantiate every complex type `Shrimps, Worms...` before saving**.

You can read more about this convention at: [Complex Types of Nullable Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380702/entity-framework-complex-types-of-nullable-values)
or [Complex Types Nullability Convention](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/50d33271-c8e3-468f-82e1-7c3178cb4322/complex-types-nullability-convention?forum=adonetefx)